# Why does my dynamically allocated array get initialized to 0?

Tags: c++, arrays, gdb

I have some code that creates a dynamically allocated array with

```
int *Array = new int[size];
```

From what I understand, Array should be a pointer to the first item of Array in memory. When using gdb, I can call x Array to examine the value at the first memory location, x Array+1 to examine the second, etc. I expect to have junk values left over from whatever application was using those spots in memory prior to mine. However, using x Array returns 0x00000000 for all those spots. What am I doing wrong? Is my code initializing all of the values of the Array to zero?

EDIT: For the record, I ask because my program is an attempt to implement this: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time/. I want to make sure that my algorithm isn't incrementing through the array to initialize every element to 0.

Comment: You can't rely on this behavior, it's UB!

Comment: You can write `int *Array = new int[size]();` (note the empty trailing parenthesis) if you ever want those zeros guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most modern OSes, the OS gives zeroed pages to applications, as opposed to letting information seep between unrelated processes.  That's important for security reasons, for example.  Back in the old DOS days, things were a bit more casual.  Today, with memory protected OSes, the OS generally gives you zeros to start with.

So, if this `new` happens early in your program, you're likely to get zeros.  You'd be crazy to rely on that though; it's undefined behavior if you do.

If you keep allocating, filling, and freeing memory, eventually `new` will return memory that isn't zeroed.  Rather, it'll contain remnants of your process' own earlier scribblings.

And there's *no guarantee* that any particular call to `new`, even at the beginning of your program, will return memory filled with zeros.  You're just *likely* to see that for calls to `new` early in your program.  *Don't let that mislead you.*

Answer (score 1):

> I expect to have junk values left over from whatever application was using those spots

It's certainly possible but by no means guaranteed. Particularly in debug builds, you're just as likely to have the runtime zero out that memory (or fill it with some recognisable bit pattern) instead, to help you debug things if you use the memory incorrectly.

And, really, "those spots" is a rather loose term, given virtual addressing.

**The important thing is that, no, your code is *not* setting all those values to zero.**

Comment: In a modern VM OS, I'd be rather disappointed if it let me see other tasks' discarded memory willy nilly, unless I did something far less pedestrian than a simple `new`.

Comment: @g-makulik : I expect junk from within the same application; I was just pointing out with virtual memory in a modern VM OS, you shouldn't expect to see junk from _arbitrary other_ applications.  (The "those spots" commentary.)

Comment: @JoeZ Yes, it's kinda odd question. Usually it's asked vice versa. But UB hmm, simply stays UB ...